# Transfer weight paint from character to Heels while character isn't in rest position

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

I don't know if this is possible, but might as well ask before trying some other stuff:

I have got this character in a standard flat footed T-Pose as rest pose. I added some heels I liked and to sculpt the heels to fit her feet shape better, I changed her pose from rest into an heeled version. Sculpted the heels to fit better, and thats where i'm at now.

Now I want to add the heels to her Rig. For Cloths I normally just transfer the weight painting from the character to the clothing, but this doesn't work on the heels, since she isn't in her rest position. The heels deform since the Rig is deformed.

Is there a way to do this? Copy the weight paint from the character to the heels, while she is in her heeled pose? Otherwise I got to refit her feels to her rest-position before weight transferring which will be a pain in the ass.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not really the weights.  It's that the rest pose doesn't match what it should be for the shoes.  Armature deformation is relative to the rest pose of the armature + mesh, and it's way worth spending some time getting comfortable with that.  For a quick fix, you could consider applying the armature modifier on the character, applying pose as rest pose on the armature, data transfer weights to heels, then give both heels and mesh an appropriate armature modifier.  Not ideal (applying armature isn't really reversible, you lose volume.)